# Display the score in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am completely new to unity. I am making a simple 2d platformer game using unity. Can somebody help me to display the score on the game. I am storing the value on a int variable. Below is the c# code i used for the distance covered.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class distanc : MonoBehaviour {
    private int dist;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () 
    {
        dist = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        dist = dist+=1 * Time.deltaTime;
        print("Dist:" + dist);
    }
}
```

what i want is to display the **dist** value on the screen. I have placed a GUI Text on the screen.

Comment: I suggest you go through the [unity3d tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules). The space shooter one in particular has details on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it simple, you can do - where you are printing the dist - something like this:

```
GameObject.Find("GUIText").guiText.text = dist;
```

, supposing that your GUIText object is called `GUIText`.
Basically, with that, you will find an object of that name, access its `text` component, and modify it with `dist` value.